# Lace head covers

Tags: synagogue, head-covering

Why do some women wear those lace coverings in shul? Is it so that they should not pray or recite berachot without their head covered or is it out of respect for shul? Also, when did this practice start?

Rav Shlomo Zalman is quoted(Tefilah Kehilchata 7:74 (notes); Halichot Shlomo Tefila 2:17) as saying that the custom by married women is to cover their heads (not necessarily their hair). Are these lace covers meant to comply with this minhag or are they just for shul?

Comment: I think the women think that someone may put a dish on their head :-) (Those things look like doilies.) Actually, I think it is for respect for the shul. There is a separate issue with covering one's hair, and many will already wear a hat or shaitel to do that job. Perhaps, wearing something on the head is better than nothing, in that sense. It seems to be a largely U.S. practice that may have begun in Conservative / Reform shuls. I went to an Orthodox shul in the 60's and most women did not cover their heads with anything. A few wore hats, but, I think it was mainly for fashion.

Comment: Do these lace things actually accomplish anything, since you can see right through them?

Comment: There is a discussion of whether women need to cover their heads when they pray and recite berachot, just like men do. Rav Shlomo Zalman is quoted (Tefilah Kehilchata 7:74 (notes); Halichot Shlomo Tefila 2:17) as saying that the custom by married women is to cover their heads (not necessarily their hair). I am asking specifically regarding these doilies are they worn for Shul or for prayers?  It may be just for Shul, because women don't put them on every time they recite a beracha. On the other hand, it may be a distortion of the minhag of covering their heads when they recite a beracha.

Comment: @DonielF Of course they accomplish something. Even a Kalta fulfills Dat Moshe!

Comment: I'm getting confusion. Is the quesion about Shul or prayers at home in private?  Is it a general head covering or just for single women in Shul?

Comment: @gamliela Seems to be for married women in shul. AFAIK these are for women without their heads covered; only married women in public require their heads covered.

Comment: @DoubleAA Got it. Not at all what I thought you meant by Kalta.

Comment: @DonielF According to many (most?) Rishonim, a Kalta is some sort of woven basket that you can see through the holes, and that's why it doesn't fulfill Dat Yehudit.

Comment: @doneilf I know about married women and head covering, so this is what I found confusing. A lace doily really wouldn't be sufficient in shul for a married woman, so its only for singles. Still, is it for prayers st home, like any time, a sort of veil or what?

Comment: Just to be clear. The discussion is NOT about covering hair but about covering heads - like a kippah. The question is what is this custom trying to accomplish - to have heads covered in Shul or to have heads covered for prayers.